# "El operando debe tener una columna" al hacer una subconsulta en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una subconsulta SQL pero no soy capaz de dar en el clavo. La consulta como la tengo ahora está así:

```
SELECT `IdPedido` 
FROM `pedidos_remoto` 
WHERE `IdPedido` IN (SELECT * FROM `pedidos_remoto` 
                   WHERE (`agencia`='Agencia X' OR `agencia`='Agencia Y') 
                   AND DATE (`fecha`)=2020-07-22
                   )
```

Básicamente quiero que me saque los IdPedido de la tabla pedidos_remoto dónde la agencia es X o Y y la fecha la marcada. Sin embargo, al ejecutarlo en SQL me dice que el operando debe tener una columna. ¿Dónde está el fallo? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo dos problemas en tu consulta, el primero es el que hace saltar el error, debes sustituir el asterisco (*) de la subconsulta por el nombre del campo a buscar (parece que pueda ser `IdPedido`).

El segundo problema es que la fecha del `WHERE` debe ir rodeada de comillas simples:

```
SELECT `IdPedido` 
FROM `pedidos_remoto` 
WHERE `IdPedido` IN (SELECT `IdPedido` FROM `pedidos_remoto` 
                   WHERE (`agencia`='Agencia X' OR `agencia`='Agencia Y') 
                   AND DATE (`fecha`) = '2020-07-22'
                   )
```

Aunque viendo la consulta en su conjunto, la subconsulta no parece necesaria pues hace referencia a la misma tabla:

```
SELECT `IdPedido` 
FROM `pedidos_remoto` 
WHERE (`agencia`='Agencia X' OR `agencia`='Agencia Y') 
AND DATE (`fecha`) = '2020-07-22'
```

Comment: Bien visto lo de la sub-consulta no necesaria. Ante  caso tan extraño me pregunto que hará el SGBD  (cuando se usa una sub-consulta sin necesidad, sobre la misma tabla).